# Handling a Firestore map object in Swift 5

Tags: dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, document, swift5

I was struggling yesterday to handle in a SWIFT app a Firestore map object that had a variable size so I though to share my solution.

The document contained a map like this:

```
{"07:45"=9;"09:56"=4;"13:12"=16}
```

The problem was that there could be more or less fields and the field names are unknown in advance, so it was not possible to know how many elements there were or even the names of the fields. For this reason I couldn't address the fields directly by just reading it into a dictionary. On top of that, as dictionaries is not ordered, I couldn't just address the elements in the dictionary by index.

I solved this by first reading the map into a dictionary, sorting it into an array, and then addressing the index of the array I wanted.

```
     db.document(eventID).getDocument{ (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let let data = document.data()
            let timeslots = data!["times"] as! Dictionary<String, Int>
            let self.count = timeslots.count. // To use elsewhere
            let sortedTimes = self.timeslots.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })  // Sort by key value which contains times as strings.
            print(sortedTimes[0].value)  // Just to print the value of the first tuple. NB sortedTimes is an Array of key,value pairs.
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
```

Comment: a have a feeling that you chose a wrong data structure, 2 arrays + simple client side mapping should do the job

Comment: That'd be an easy data structure to deal with from the app side but the wrong data structure for the project. Arrays are independent and there is a strong dependency between the key and the value here. It's  like saying we don't need dictionary structures because we could just use two arrays instead.